# MySQL duplicates results even after using DISTINCT every time I try to show more than one field of the same table

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, distinct

I have a MySQL query that shows a list of items after joining two tables:

```
SELECT contenidos.tituloContenido FROM contenidos
JOIN cursosContenidos ON cursosContenidos.contenidoID = contenidos.contenidoID
WHERE cursosContenidos.cursoID = ?;
```

There's no problem with this query, but, when I change it to show another field of the contenidos table, the results are duplicated.

So they get duplicated when doing:

```
SELECT contenidos.contenidoID, contenidos.tituloContenido FROM contenidos
JOIN cursosContenidos ON cursosContenidos.contenidoID = contenidos.contenidoID
WHERE cursosContenidos.cursoID = ?;
```

I've tried adding a `GROUP BY cursosContenidos.contenidoID` clause, and `DISTINCT` as well, but they keep appearing duplicated. Any idea on why?

To retrieve the results, I'm using PHP:

```
$mostrarContenidos = $conectar1->prepare("
      SELECT contenidos.tituloContenido FROM contenidos
      JOIN cursosContenidos ON cursosContenidos.contenidoID = contenidos.contenidoID
      WHERE cursosContenidos.cursoID = ?;
    ");
  $mostrarContenidos->bindParam(1, $cursoID);
  $mostrarContenidos->execute();
  $contenidos = $mostrarContenidos->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  if ($contenidos) {
    echo '<h2>Contenidos del Curso</h2>';
    foreach ($contenidos as $value) {
      echo 'Id: '.$contenidos['contenidoID'].'<br>';
      echo 'Title: '.$contenidos['tituloContenido'].'<br>';
    } 
  } else {
    echo 'error retrieving results';
  }
```

**The expected result is:**

```
Id: 1

Title This is my super title
```

**What I get:**

```
Id: 1

Title This is my super title
Id: 1
Title This is my super title
```

Comment: Please add example data and expected output. The combination of the columns is not duplicated I presume. What exactly do you need?

Comment: Have you tried `GROUP BY contenidos.contenidoID, contenidos.tituloContenido`?

Comment: If you use `distinct` on your example it **can't** be duplicated. Is this really your query or do you output mre columns?

Comment: It is the real query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL query is most likely *not* returning multiple rows - you are only outputting it twice. This is because your `foreach` statement loops over each column in the single row you've fetched, rather than each row of the result set.

To clarify a bit further, this line just fetches the first (and probably only) row:

`$contenidos = $mostrarContenidos->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

The foreach loop goes through each *column* in the row, and outputs info about the whole row for each column.

If you want `$contenidos` to be an array of all rows, you could do this instead:

`$contenidos = $mostrarContenidos->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in the query, but in the php.

In your foreach-loop you assign the result-array-elements to $value, but then you don't use $value.
You should use :

```
   echo 'Id: '.$value['contenidoID'].'<br>';
   echo 'Title: '.$value['tituloContenido'].'<br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it: `GROUP BY contenidos.contenidoID, contenidos.tituloContenido`

Answer (score 0):

Should  work with distinct

```
 SELECT distinct contenidos.contenidoID, contenidos.tituloContenido FROM contenidos
 JOIN cursosContenidos ON cursosContenidos.contenidoID = contenidos.contenidoID
 WHERE cursosContenidos.cursoID = ?;
```